# Iterate through object in React - "expression expected"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, types

I have following source code:

```
export const LinksPure = (props: AllProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { component } = props;

  return (
    <DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.links')}>
      {Object.keys(component?.external_links?).map((item, index) => {

      })}
    </DetailsBox>
  );
};
```

types for TypeScript:

```
export const ExternalLinks = Record({});
const SharedComponentDetailsFields = {
  id: Number,
  name: String.Or(Null),
  description: String.Or(Null),
  reference: String,
  manufacturer: String,
  integration_effort: Number,
  attachments: Attachments,
  prices: Prices,
  spec: String.Or(Null),
  task_id: Number.Or(Null),
  updated_at: String,
  notes: String.Or(Null),
  external_links: ExternalLinks,
  use_cases: Array(UseCase),
};
```

All I want to do is to iterate thorugh `external_links` field, but got error:

[image]

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding that `?` at the end `component?.external_links?`

Comment: It is optional chaining.

Comment: @AtifSaddique That's optional chaining, to ensure it doesn't error if `component` happens to be undefined or null

Comment: for that, you don't need to put `?` at the end, `component?.external_links` is enough and change it like this : `Object.keys(component?.external_links || {})`

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk By using the ?. operator instead of just ., JavaScript knows to implicitly check to be sure obj.first is not null or undefined before attempting to access obj.first.second. If obj.first is null or undefined, the expression automatically short-circuits, returning undefined. Check In Steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to put the optional chain's question mark after the `)`, just before the `.` for the syntax to be valid, but you also can't call `Object.keys` on something that isn't defined. `Object.keys` will return an array or throw, so the optional chain for the `.map` isn't needed.

Try something like

```
{Object.keys(component?.external_links ?? {}).map((item, index) => {

})}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Snow what does `?? {}` do exactly?

Comment: @Dax `??` is nullish coalescing. If the left side is undefined or null, the whole expression will evaluate to the right side. It's similar to `||`, except more specific.

Comment: This syntax is needed to prevent `Object.keys` to throw errors incase `external_links` is undefined? So to counter this we give the map function an empty object to loop over?

Comment: @Snow Any idea how to get value for every key?

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk The first argument for the `.map` callback is the item being iterated over. So, above, each key is put into the `item` variable name in an iteration.